# tcpdump: How to capture arrival / outgoing interface for a packet?

Tags: port, pcap, tcpdump

I would like to capture the "incoming" interface and "outgoing" interface for packets transiting through a software switch (assume it has 10 ports and I want to know which of those 10 interfaces a particular packet came from).  I can't seem to find any way to get "tcpdump -i any" to output the arriving or outgoing interfaces.  It only gives fields of the packet. Is there any other derivative of tcpdump (like tshark perhaps?) which will enable extracting the port information? The intention is tracing a packet flow path through a network. Regards.

Comment: each interface will have its own mac address (unless they are on a vlan) so why not use tcpdump -enns0 -i any and translate the mac to interface name?

Comment: Amadain .. the received mac address will not be that of the switch's ingress port.  It will be that of the host connected to the switch. That is:  Host1(Mac-H1)-----(Port1)SWITCH(Port2)-----Host2(Mac-H2). If I do tcpdump -i any on SWITCH, then received mac address is Mac-H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tcpdump` 4.10 should include [this feature](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/296) (hasn't been released as of today).

Meanwhile you can use [Sebastian Haas's script](https://serverfault.com/a/660350/65750).